# what's the mean of "reshape(-1,1,2)"

Tags: python, numpy

```
x = np.linspace(0,10, 5)
y = 2*x
points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
```

What's the mean of the third line?I know the mean of `reshape(m,n)`, but what does `reshape(-1, 1, 2)` means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, so I'm guessing the `-1` part is what troubles you.

From the [documantaion](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape):

> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

The whole line meaning is this (breaking it down for simplicity):

1. `points = np.array([x, y])` -> create a `2 X 5` np.array consisting of `x,y`
2. `.T` -> transpose
3. `.reshape(-1, 1, 2)` -> reshape it, in this case to a `5X1X2` array (as can seen by the output of `points.shape` [(5L, 1L, 2L)])

Comment: I have figured out what's the meaning of the third line. "np.array([x,y])" lets me get a two dimensional array and "T.reshape(-1,1,2)" transfers it to 3 dimensional array. And the meaning of  -1, as what you have said.

Comment: Not exactly. the `.T` is transpose. I edited my A for clarity

Answer (score 0):

```
vertices = np.array([[100,300],[200,200],[400,300],[200,400]],np.int32)
vertices.shape
pts = vertices.reshape((-1,1,2))
```

[refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bokQc.png)

Consider the above code
here we have created set of vertices for to be plotted on a image using opencv but opencv expects 3d array but we only have vertices in 2d array.So the `.reshape((-1,1,2))` allows us to keep the original array intact while adding the 3rd dimension to the array(Notice the extra brackets added to the list).This third dimension coontains the details for colors i.e RGB